# Alert event handler

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 2 functions which are dependent on each other. func1 is a method returning a value from database. If there is an error executing func1, an alert box shows and I dont want to execute func2. If func1 executes successfully without an error, then only I want func2 to get executed. I dont know how to achieve this. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Kevin.

Comment: What language are you using? Javascript? C++?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but isn't as simple as:

```
    private function getData():void
    {
        //get data

        if (data)
        {
            onDataLoad();
        }
        else
        {
           //alert();
        }
    }

    private function onDataLoad():void
    {
        //do something
    }
```

Or, if your data load function returns a boolean, just work it into a similar scenario.

Comment: May b i shud have explained it more clearly. func1 is a method <mx:method name="insertRecord" result="insertHandler2()" fault="mx.controls.Alert.show('Error inserting data', 'Error!')"/>
if the above method is successful, then func2 should b executed which is also a simialr method which inserts data. If Func1 raises an error then func2 doesnt gets executed. I hope its clear now.

Comment: So you have two classes here? what does your dataload method return? As I edited, if you simply type the return as a boolean, you could easily run a conditional statement in your calling class.

Comment: My dataload functions func1 and func2 doesnt return a value. it just inserts data into a table.May be am not being clear here.

Comment: I gotcha. I'm not really certain about conditional statements in a <mx:method> - I've not needed them before, and I actually couldn't find any decent discussion on the webs. I think you may need to run this statement through a <mx:script>, calling the insertRecord() manually.

Comment: Thats what am trying to do through <mx:script>. method1 is calling insertRecord1() and method2 calls insertRecord2() private functions. What I really need is, if insertRecord1() doesnt throw an error then only I want to call insertRecord2(). am confused..

Answer (score -1):

the function `func1` should throw an error (A) or return an error code / null pointer (B).

(A)

```
try {
    func1();
    func2(); // only executed if func1 does not throw any errors
} catch (e:Error) {
    // error handling
}
```

(B)

```
var myData:Object = func1();
if(myData != null) {
    func2();
}
```